# Reading SQLite Database as File in C#

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, filestream, outputstream

I'm having a little wrinkle in my head on how to read my SQLite Database that comes from my NexusOne and read it to my PC using C#.Net.

In the initial load of my android app the database will be copy from Asset to `/data/data/com.example.myapp/databases` as `OutputStream`. Here is the code.

```
        //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
```

I created a C# program to read the SQLite Database but when initializing the Connection using `System.Data.SQLite` it always throw an error "no such table error".

When I place a breakpoint in `SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDB.db")`, `connection.DataBase` is always equal to "**main**". Database name should be "MyDB" not "main". Seems like my sqlite database file failed to read maybe because it was created using `Stream` or maybe because it is not a Data Base File? Because when I check the file type it says "File" not "Database File".

Anyone have an idea on how to read the sqlite database file using C#. The first thing comes in my mind is to use `FileStream` and `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`. But I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [SQLite Admin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/), to see for sure the names of the tables in your database or even if it can be opened.  Then once you have that information, you should be able to open the database with SQLiteConnection object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using SQLite Database Browser to browse my data and I know that the table is there.

Comment: @klaydze Throw up your table on some site, I'll take a look.